# how to view two dialog box on the linux console? running on the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dialog, tput

I want to view on the Linux console two dialog windows on the same time
one window that view the progress BAR
and the second tailbox that view the logs are running.

The problem is that the dialog present in the central of the console

What I want is to view the two dialog boxes on the same time on the console while the progress BAR is on the top of the screen
and the tail BOX should present down in the screen.

- How to implement this?
- How to place the dialog window up or down and not in the center ?

  ```
  dialog --title "RUN TASKS FROM TEXT TABLE" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 70 0


  dialog --tailbox file.log 10 100
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to get this to work, using `--tailboxbg`, followed by `--and-widget` and then `--gauge`.  The positioning of the widgets is straightforward, using the `--begin` option.  The complication is in handling input from the keyboard: dialog makes a special case for allowing multiple `-tailboxbg` options by polling input across the corresponding windows.  That polling "works" for similar widgets (which have input), but `--gauge` does not use input from the keyboard.